# VBA : What is the best way to verify condition before assigned value to a cell

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization

For my internship, I am working on an Excel workbook that is treating a lot of values (approx. 60000 rows and 40 columns) and i need to have the fastest treatment of data. The file is composed of 4 worksheets:

- the 1st ("DATA") one stores the basic data
- the 2ed ("TREATMENT") one receives the data, treat them with intern excel functions and instructions: VLOOKUP, SUM, AVERAGE,IF,OR,AND
- the 3rd ("RESULTS") receives the final values from worksheet 2 in a table
- the 4th ("Index") is not important

All this transfers of data and calculations between them are done by lines like those one:

```
=IF(OR(K4567=0;K4567="hors ligne");IF(OR(J4567<3,5;K4567="hors ligne");1;0);0)
```

```
=IF($I$2=0;VLOOKUP($A4565;DATA!$A$10:$AG$52560;2);IF($I$2=DATA!AU4560;VLOOKUP($A4565;DATA!$A$10:$AG$52560;2);""))
```

```
=D52082 (Cells F5 get the value from D52082)
```

A small macro in "RESULTS" enable to retrieve the final values in "TREATMENT" depending on the month, but the process is too long.

My aim is -------------------------> TO MAKE IT AS FAST AS A BLINK OF AN EYE

I made a lot of research and it seems that WELL programmed macros is the solution.

I made a macro to replace this line that is used for a full column :

```
=IF($I$2=0;VLOOKUP($A9730;DATA!$A$10:$AG$52560;2);IF($I$2=DATA!AU9725;VLOOKUP($A9730;DATA!$A$10:$AG$52560;2);""))
```

CODE:

```
Public Sub colonne_G()
    Dim wsht_TREATMENT As Worksheet, wsht_DATA As Worksheet
    Set wsht_TREATMENT = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TREATMENT")
    Set wsht_DATA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim RowCount As Long, ColumnCount As Long, i As Integer
    With wsht_DATA
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row            'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE LIGNES
        ColumnCount = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE COLONNES
    End With
    
    Dim tab_Date() As Variant
    'ReDim tab_Date(1 To RowCount)
    tab_Date = wsht_DATA.Range("B10:B" & RowCount) 'RECUPERE TOUTES LES DATES

    For i = 1 To UBound(tab_Date, 1)
        If wsht_TREATMENT.Range("I2") = 0 Or wsht_TREATMENT.Range("I2") = Month(tab_Date(i, 1)) Then
            wsht_TREATMENT.Range("G" & 14 + i).Value = tab_Date(i, 1)
        Else
            wsht_TREATMENT.Range("G" & 14 + i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

However, is it way to slow... The problem is that for each value of tab_Date we verify the condition and depending on that we send a value in the cell. Instead of that, should i change the value of the tab, and at the end paste all the tab in the column ?

SOLUTION:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(tab_Date, 1)
     If wsht_TREATMENT.Range("I2") = 0 Or wsht_TREATMENT.Range("I2") = Month(tab_Date(i, 1)) Then
           tab_Date(i, 1) = tab_Date(i, 1)
     Else
           tab_Date(i, 1) = vbnullstring
     End If

Next i
wsht_TREATMENT.Range("G15:G" & RowCount) = Application.Transpose(tab_Date)
```

HERE ARE MY QUESTIONS:

- Is it better in terms of speed to replace functions like VLOOKUP, SUM, etc by macros ?
- Is it faster to use macros to transfer values from a cell to another one ? (from what i have understood it is the case when it is a Range of cells that is transfer to another one)
- Do you have a better solution for my code?
- Is it better to directly specify in which range the value of the array should be sent (eg :wsht_TREATMENT.Range("G15:G" & RowCount)) or to resize it (eg: wsht_TREATMENT.Range("G15").resize(RowCount)
- Do you want more informations about how the files works ?**

Here is the code that return the same values in the column:

```vb
Public Sub colonne_G()
    Dim wsht_Eol As Worksheet, wsht_DATA As Worksheet
    Set wsht_Eol = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Eolienne")
    Set wsht_DATA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    
    Dim RowCount As Long, ColumnCount As Long, i As Integer
    With wsht_DATA
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row            'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE LIGNES
        ColumnCount = .Cells(7, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'COMPTE LE NOMBRE DE COLONNES'
    End With
    
    Dim rgCondition As Range
    Set rgCondition = wsht_Eol.Range("I2")
    Dim tab_Date() As Variant, tab_result() As Variant

    tab_Date = wsht_DATA.Range("B10:B" & RowCount) 'RECUPERE TOUTES LES DATES
   
    ReDim tab_result(1 To UBound(tab_Date, 1))
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(tab_Date, 1)
        If rgCondition = 0 Or rgCondition = Month(tab_Date(i, 1)) Then
            tab_result(i) = tab_Date(i, 1)
        Else
            tab_result(i) = ""
        End If
    Next i
wsht_Eol.Range("G15").Resize(UBound(tab_Date, 1)) = tab_result 
End Sub
```

Comment: You use one variant array.  You need to have all ranges as variant arrays and use an variant array to store the output.  Do not refer to ranges in the worksheet in a loop at all.  Do all your checking with variant arrays.

Comment: Also in your solution you are still referring to the worksheet range.  put wsht_TREATMENT.Range("I2") as a variable so you do not constantly to the worksheet.  Also I do not think you should be transposing the array when applying it to the range after the loop.

Comment: Thank you @ScottCraner for your answer!

Comment: FYI typically `VLOOKUP()` has a final FALSE argument (exact match).  Just wanted to make sure that's intentionally omitted.

Comment: I have change my code with what I thought and you're right about transposing the array. The process lasted first 1.65 sec and when I put wsht_TREATMENT.Range("I2") in a variable it  decreased to 1.5 sec. However, i get the first value of tab_result in all the column i don't know why because my tab_result is well filled:

Comment: As a general hint: every interaction from code to a range costs time. Best to do the calculations in big chumps. So prevent looping over each cell (a cell is a range to). This does not mean btw that you should write you're own sum or vlookup functions. 60k x 40 shouldn't be that much of a deal.

Comment: Besides, the vlookups surely take most of the time to calculate. Each cell loops over 60k values and returns a match, and that is done 60k times. This means just for one column 3.6 million (60k * 60k) values are compared. That's a lot of calculation. In reality it's maybe only a third, as vlookup returns the first match, but it's a lot. Maybe you can create distinct values from the lookup ranges? F.e. If there are only 100 distinct values in that 60k column, that vlookup wouldn't really need to loop over 60k values (60 times).

Comment: Yes, def forget about the rest. Vlookups are slowing down your file mostly. Another tip: to limit the looking-up action of vlookups (if multiple columns look up the same value) create a column that uses MATCH function. The return of this value can then be used by multiple other columns that use the INDEX function. For example VLOOKUP($A9730;DATA!$A$10:$AG$52560;2) becomes MATCH($A9730;DATA!$10:$AG$52560;0) in cells X10:52560 and INDEX($B10:$B$52560; $X9730) in colum Y. And then another column can use that same lookup nr from column X.

Comment: If you are an intern with research time on your hands and you already understand programming fundamentals, why don't you just dump VBA (gasp!) and read this data into `python` and perform the calculations there.  It'd be much cleaner & faster.

Comment: @AirSquid I've done research on that and i didn't really get how to do it. But it seems to be a good idea